# Storing IP addresses in JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, cmd, ip-address, ping

I have a total of 7 machines in a test setup that run test scripts between any two combinations of those machines. These scripts require the IP address of the machines involved in the test run. I'd like to store each machine's IP address in a variable to not only make it easier to reference and call in our JavaScript test scripts, but also design the variables so that they'll be set by pinging the machine to get an up to date version of said address. I don't expect them to change, but you never know what might happen and this would allow to completely ignore them for the most part.

We're using Squish as our IDE for running JavaScript test scripts and Squish has an in house function `OS.system` that lets you run the command prompt.

It's probably obvious that I can't just use something like `const pc1 = OS.system("ping pc-name")` since ping gives a return far more than just the IP address.

I was wondering if there was a simpler way to pass a machine's ip address to a JavaScript variable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which OS you are using but you can do something like that in Linux bash:

```
ping -c 1 google.de | grep PING | awk '{print $3}'
```

But I would recommend you to use a library for that. 
You can take a look at this: (node.js)
https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html

Comment: I would recommend you to use backticks and ES6 syntax to not have any problems with the special chars e.g. const x = OS.system(\`ping -c 1 ${youhostname} ..... \`)

Comment: Unfortunately we're working in an environment that prohibits unapproved libraries. I could try to get it approved though.

Comment: There is another way. You can use the google dns which provides and https API which is really simple. e.g. "https://dns.google.com/resolve?name=google.de&type=A" Of course if your hosts are not resolvable by the public DNS it will not work

Comment: We're operating offline using JavaScript as a scripting language. Well offline from the internet. We can ping computers on the internal network. I was thinking about a way to save the result of a ping to a variable. However, I think it might be difficult without you all being able to see how OS.system functions.

Comment: Ok, which OS you are using?

Comment: If you are using Windows maybe this can be helpful: https://superuser.com/questions/812664/nslookup-command-line-with-a-record-ip-as-sole-output
Or you can send me the output of your simple ping command and I can see how to use built in string manipulation of javascript

Comment: We're using Windows. Output of a ping would look like:

Comment: Pinging [computer-name] [ipaddress] with 32 bytes of data: and then 4 replys with ipaddress, bytes=32, time and ttl

Comment: Is this the string what will be in your variable after execute?

Comment: If this is the string you can use `yourvariable.split(' ')[2].replace(/\[|]/g, '')`  . If the "[" "]" are just in your censored version then you can skip the replace method

Comment: when I try to save the ping result with a JavaScript varialbe I just get 0.

Comment: I'm sure "0" is the exit code of the process. Try to find out how you can get the `stout` of the command.